# Can I edit body's innerText without altering html tags?

Tags: javascript, html

In a script, I have this line :

```
var ReplacingScope = document.querySelector( "body" );
let Regexp = new RegExp("fdp", 'gi');
ReplacingScope.innerText = ReplacingScope.innerText.replace( Regexp,"pdf");
```

It does what I want, which is to replace all *fdp* occurences to *pdf*, but it also removes the html tags.
For example, I'd want it to do :

```html
<body>
<div id="test">fdp</div>
</body>
```

becomes

```html
<body>
<div id="test">pdf</div>
</body>
```

I don't want to use `innerHTML` property because it would possibly make bugs, changing node ids, classes, etc...
Is there a way to only edit the text of the body while conserving all the html tags ?
Thank you

Comment: No, I want to keep the div while replacing, like that : `<div id="test>pdf</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to do a find-and-replace like that in one go while maintaining the DOM tree.

One solution is to traverse the DOM manually and do the text replacement in each text node, but this won't work for matching text that spans across multiple nodes.

```js
function replace() {
  const regex = /is|am|123456/gi;
  const el = document.querySelector('#box');
  const walker = document.createTreeWalker(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);

  while (walker.nextNode()) {
    const node = walker.currentNode;
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(regex, '***');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="replace()">Replace</button>

<div id="box">
  <p>This is some <strong>sample</strong> text.</p>
  <p>123456 123<strong>456</strong> <em>123456</em></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this to achieve what you want:

```
var ReplacingScope = document.getElementById("test");
let Regexp = new RegExp("fdp", 'gi');
ReplacingScope.innerText = ReplacingScope.innerText.replace( Regexp,"pdf");
```